# Can not delete a number in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to restrict an edit text to input a  number from 60 to 3600. To do that I have used TextWatcher. The application is programmed to replace any number less than 60 with 60 and any number greater then 3600 with 3600 But when the application runs and i give a number less then 60 as input it automatically replaces that number with 60 and now if I try to delete that number and input and new number in its place I cannot do so. For example at first I input 3 in the edit text so it automatically converts that number to 60. Now I decided to delete 60 and enter a new number in its place i can not do so. So someone please help me to solve this problem. Bellow is the code I am using to restrict the edit text.

```
etNumPicures.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            try {

                // Log.d("Percentage", "input: " + s);

                if (Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) < 60) {
                    s.replace(0, s.length(), "60");
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter a number between 60 to 3600. Any number less then 60 will be replaced by 60",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) > 3600) {
                    s.replace(0, s.length(), "3600");
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter a number between 0 to 6. Any number greater then 3600 will be replaced by 3600",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            }

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: working fine for me...

Answer (score 4):

The error is logical :P When you enter, say, number 4, the TextWatcher will convert it to 60. All good here.

BUT! If you now erase number 0 in attempt to insert another, the TextWatcher will see a number 6 in there and again set it to 60!

You need to think of a different validation strategy here :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kelevandos. Can you suggest any validation strategy that might solve this problem?

Comment: I will assume the TextView is a part of a larger form, which gets confirmed at some point, e.g. a Button click? If yes, check the contents of the box when the form is confirmed and forbid it from passing.

Answer (score 1):

Currently what you are doing will never work as when you delete any digit from 60 it will again get less than 60 and will replace it with 60.

So would suggest you to use OnFocusChangeListener. Sample code for it as below:

```
etNumPicures.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus){
             if (etNumPicures.getText() != null) {
                 try{ 
                     int i = Integer.valueOf(etNumPicures.getText().toString());
                     if (i < 60) {
                         etNumPicures.setText("60");
                     else if (i > 3600){
                         etNumPicures.setText("3600");
                     }

                 }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                     etNumPicures.setText("60");  
                 }
             }
        }
    }
});
```

Here hasFocus is true when view has focus and false when view lost focus.

Answer (score 0):

you can try;

```
s.clear();
s.insert(0,"60");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you should do it using text change events. I would suggest to try value replacement when you try to leave the edit field (i.e. you are done editing) :

```
etNumPicures.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
  public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(!hasFocus) {
     // Replace value if needed...
    }
  }
});
```